# Python Seaborn FacetGrid different y-axis

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, yaxis

I'm using `sns.FacetGrid` to plot 10 subplots. I'd like to flex the y-axis to be different for each subplot.

At the moment it automatically uses the same for all subplots. Would it be possible to customize it to make it more specific for each subplot?

Comment: Yes, use `sharey=False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation for facet grid [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)

> `share{x,y}bool, ‘col’, or ‘row’` optional If True, the facets will
>   share y axes across columns and/or x axes across rows.

Be advised that this also breaks alignment across columns and will most likely not produce the results you intended. One Y axis will be displayed, which will be only valid for the leftmost plot.